# Anyway to make Union statements smaller?

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway I can make this statement smaller? for efficiency, the whole idea is to get 
todays, this month and last months amount of "quotes".

```
    SELECT COUNT(QuoteDate) AS today
    FROM database
    WHERE QuoteDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

    UNION

    SELECT COUNT(QuoteDate) AS this_month
    FROM database
    WHERE QuoteDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

    UNION

    SELECT COUNT(QuoteDate) AS last_month
    FROM database 
    WHERE QuoteDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just use an OR statement?

```
 SELECT COUNT(QuoteDate) AS today FROM database
    WHERE 
     QuoteDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
     OR 
     QuoteDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
     OR
     QuoteDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

Comment: This would only return the number of quotes of the last 2 months, since the first two where clauses are always true, when the third is.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
SELECT
    sum(if(quotedate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0)) AS today,
    sum(if(quotedate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS this_month,
    sum(if(quotedate <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS last_month
FROM database
WHERE QuoteDate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

The idea is to move the selection made in the where clause to the field clause and do the calculation there.

Note, that the third clause is reversed, as you might only want those entries which are older than 1 month.